# Project home page's URL changed.... how to fix?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

The project home page's URL changed because of unknown for me reason. Two days ago it was:
**http://localhost:8080/simpleblog/** now it is **http://localhost:8080/mvc3/**. This happened after i have tried to add some views to the home controller, but i didn't change the controller's mapping, only the views.

The homecontroller is looking in the following way:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(Locale locale, Model model) 
{
    logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());
    logger.info("Running SIMPLE_BLOG");

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);       
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);     
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    // Check for compatibility
    List listTopic = entityManager.createQuery("select o from Topic o").getResultList(); // delete the last 'o' if an error occurs 

    //model.addAttribute("Topics", listTopic);

    return new ModelAndView("home", "model", listTopic);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView Create(Locale locale, Model model)
{
    Topic newTopic = new Topic();

    logger.info("HomeControlller: Create");

    List<Tag> tagList = newTopic.getTagLict();

    Hashtable modelData = new Hashtable();
    modelData.put("topic", newTopic);
    modelData.put("tagList", tagList);

    return new ModelAndView("create", modelData);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/details/(topicId)")
public ModelAndView Details(@PathVariable(value="topicId") int id) 
{
    Topic topicById = (Topic) entityManager.createQuery("select o from Topic o where o.id =: myId")
                                            .setParameter("myId", id)
                                            .getSingleResult();

    return new ModelAndView("/topic/", "model", topicById);
}
}
```

Tell me please, what I should fix to return the project's former URL

**Upd**
And in my **servlet-context.xml** i have following lines:

```
...
<context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.mvc3.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.mvc3.controller" />
...
```

And I can't find another explicit reference to the mvc3

**Upd-2**
And in my server.xml I can see the following:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true" deployXML="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
    <Context docBase="SimpleBlog" path="/mvc3" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleBlog"/>
</Host>
```

Could the Host-tag influence on the Project home page's URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your **server.xml** file must have changed, specifically the path.

In regards to yr update, your server.xml specifies it :

```
 <Context docBase="SimpleBlog" path="/mvc3" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleBlog"/>
```

change path to whatver you want it to be, which is I pressume :

```
 <Context docBase="SimpleBlog" path="/SimpleBlog" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleBlog"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The base URL of a webapp is often determined by the default webapp name, which is typically the base name of the WAR file.  Have you renamed your WAR file?

Another possibility is that you are setting the name explicitly in the servlet or container configs; e.g. the `server.xml` file or the `context.xml` file or something like that.